# how can a DataSet be filled using multiple SELECT queries run against an Excel file?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, excel

my command is something like this:

```
string command = "SELECT * FROM [SheetName1$]; SELECT * FROM [SheetName2$]; ...."
```

When I do

```
  DataSet set = new DataSet();
  using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command, connection))
  {
     adapter.Fill(ds)
  }
```

I end up with an empty DataSet (more specifically I end up with an exception that says Characters found after end of SQL statement).  However, if I use only one SELECT query this works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel cannot execute more than in one statement. Try making this in two commands.

```
DataSet set1 = new DataSet();
using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [SheetName1$];", connection))
{
   adapter.Fill(set1 );
}

DataSet set2 = new DataSet();
using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [SheetName2$];", connection))
{
   adapter.Fill(set2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of filling in `DataSet`s, fill `DataTable`s and then add said `DataTable`s to a DataSet.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables.Add("set1");
using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [SheetName1$];", connection))
{
   adapter.Fill(dt1);
}

DataTable dt2 = ds.Tables.Add("set2");
using(OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [SheetName2$];", connection))
{
   adapter.Fill(dt2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can try this in SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM [SheetName1$]
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [SheetName2$]
```

I hope this would help

Comment: not really. I need to end up with the data in separate tables